Identity matrix for non-square matrices
I am aware that this might be a trivial question, but is there an identity matrix I which has dimensions $m \times m$ for which IA=A for all matrices A with dimensions $m \times n$? I know that for square matrices, it is 1 along a diagonal and 0 for the other entries, but for non-square matrices this will be different. Thanks.

If $m \neq n$ then you cannot even multiply two $m \times n$ matrices.

but then is there a matrix I for which IA=A, where A  is a m by n matrix

The $m \times m$ identity matrix works here.

The identity matrix that is multiplication-compatible with the given matrix will work. The reason is simple, and I will illustrate this with an example. Say $m =2$ and $n = 3$. Consider the product $AB$ where
$$
A = \begin{bmatrix}
  a_{11} & a_{12} \\
  a_{21} & a_{22}
\end{bmatrix}, \quad
B = \begin{bmatrix}
  b_{11} & b_{12} & b_{13} \\
  b_{21} & b_{22} & b_{23}
\end{bmatrix}.$$
The product $AB$ can be viewed as $A$ acting on each column of $B$, as follows:
$$AB = A \begin{bmatrix}
  b_{11} & b_{12} & b_{13} \\
  b_{21} & b_{22} & b_{23}
\end{bmatrix}
= \begin{bmatrix}
  A \begin{bmatrix}
    b_{11} \\
    b_{21}
  \end{bmatrix} &
  A \begin{bmatrix}
    b_{12} \\
    b_{22}
  \end{bmatrix} &
  A \begin{bmatrix}
    b_{13} \\
    b_{23}
  \end{bmatrix}
\end{bmatrix}.$$
Then, it is clear that the matrix $A$ that sends each vector to itself (and hence $B$ to itself), is the identity $\mathbf{I}_{m}$.
The key is to realize that the left-multiplication of $A$ with $B$ is the same as $A$ acting separately on the columns on $B$.
